# Traer datos en tiempo real con php mysql y ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Amigos una pregunta tengo un archivo llamado index.php otro buscador.php y un archivo con la conexión llamado con_db.php pero no  me hace la búsqueda que quiero al presionar el button llamado buscar. El ajax no esta enviando los datos porque al otro lado al poner un `echo $_POST['buscar'];` no sale nada es decir no hay un dato que demuestre que se envió por medio de ajax

En el index.php tengo este codigo.

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
           <title>Document</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <?php include("con_db.php");   ?>
       <div class="container mt-5">  
           <div class="mb-3">
                       <label class="form-label">palabra clave</label>     
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="buscar" name="buscar"></input>
       
                       <label class="form-label">palabra busqueda instatanea</label>     
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="buscar_1" name="buscar_1">
                       <button class="btn btn-prymary" onclick="buscar_ahora($('#buscar').val());">buscar</button>
                       
                   <div  class="card col-12 mt-5">
                       <div class="card-body">
                           <div id="datos_buscador" class="container pl-5 pr-5"></div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       
       

       <script type="text/javascript">
       function buscar_ahora(buscar){
        var parametros={"buscar":buscar};
        $.ajax({
            data:parametros,
            type:'POST',
            url:'buscador.php',
            success: function(data){
                document.getElementById("datos_buscador").innerHTML = data;
       
            }
        });
       
       }
       </script>
       
       </body>
       </html>
```

En el buscador.php  tengo

```
<?php 
include("con_db.php");
           
$numero = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM productos where producto like lower('%".$_POST["buscar"]."%')");
$numero = mysqli_num_rows($buscar);
?>
<h5 class="card-tittle">resultados encontrados(<?php echo $numero; ?>):</h5>
<?php echo $resultado["cantidad"];?>
<?php while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($buscador)){?> 
           
<p class="card-text"><?php echo $resultado["producto"]; ?> - <?php echo $resultado["cantidad"];?></p>
           
<?php } ?>
```

En el archivo con_db.php tengo

```
<?php  $host = "127.0.0.1";  $user    = "root";  $clave = "123";  $bd  = "datosproductos";  $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$clave,$bd); ?>
```

Comment: Pues comienza agregando el codigo relacionado y donde esta el problema que mencionas.

Comment: ¿Qué error te envía?

Comment: ya lo pude solucionar mil gracias simplemente el en ajax debe estar en el data y el parámetro de la función el nombre de la tabla  que esta en la base de datos.